# Finding the norm of this operator

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory

I have this space $X=C([-1,1],\mathbb{C})$ the space of continous functions from $[-1,1] \to \mathbb{C}$, let $t_1,\dots,t_n \in [-1,1]$ and $c_1,\dots c_n\in \mathbb{C}$. Consider the operator: $f: X \to \mathbb{C} $ as: $$f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x(t_j).$$
I have to prove that $f$ is a bounded operator from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and find $||f||$. I have managed to prove that it is bounded, but I am having problems finding $||f||$. Recall that the norm in $X$ is the $\sup$ norm. If we denote $\gamma_j=||c_j|| $:
$$\sup_{x\in X}\frac{||f(x)||}{||x||}=\sup_{x\in X}\frac{||\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x(t_j)||}{||x||}=\sup_{x\in X} \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j \frac{||x(t_j)||}{||x||} $$
Clearly $|| f||$ depends explicitly of $\gamma_j$, but I don't know well how to continue and somehow show a more explicit number. Any ideas would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint 1:** You made a mistake, the following equality is not true:

$$
\sup_{x\in X}\frac{||\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x(t_j)||}{||x||}\neq \sup_{x\in X} \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j \frac{||x(t_j)||}{||x||}$$

**Hint 2:** For all $c_j \neq 0$ denote by $\omega_i:= \frac{c_j}{||c_j||}$.

Then
$$\|\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x(t_j)\| \leq \sum_{j=1}^n| c_j| | x(t_j)| \leq  \sum_{j=1}^n| c_j| \| x\| $$

The first inequality is equality exactly when
$$\overline{\omega_j} x(t_i)=|x(t_i)|$$
while the second is equality exactly when
$$|x(t_i)|=\|x\|$$

Comment: I think you mean $\omega_i := c_j / |c_j|$?

Comment: @angryavian yes, ty. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, from here I can follow, but still don't get why the equality is wrong, is not just a re-writing using the norm of each $c_j$?

Comment: @J.Rodriguez The triangle inequality says $$||\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x(t_j)|| \leq \sum_{j=1}^n|| c_j x(t_j)||$$ and it is easy to construct examples where the inequality is strict. You moved the sum outside the norm, when you do that you don't always get equality.

Comment: ohh god, how coudn't i see it, thanks.

Comment: @J.Rodriguez And the moment you see what you missed, the rest of the solution becomes natural

Comment: Sorry to still asking, but in the line  $\bar{\omega_j}x(t_i) = |x(t_i)|$ is confusing to me, first, the left side is a complex number, so you don't need something like a norm on it? And still not sure about why use the conjugate of $\omega$, not sure if I am doing wrong the numbers, but if I take this without the conjugate and remplace in the first sum, I think it works, am i wrong?

Comment: @J.Rodriguez $\omega_i$ is the PHASE of that complex number. Write $x(t_j)=|x(t_j)| e^{i \alpha_J}$ and set $\omega_i=e^{i \alpha_j}$